# Confused by my own argument

Tags: linear-algebra

I answered the following question:
[image]

The finite dimensional case is easy enough. Impotency gives $Ker \cap Im = \{0\}$. Lastly, the Rank Nullity theorem gives (on dimensional grounds) that hte span of the basis of the kenral and image give $V$, so done.

If $V$ is no longer fininite dimensional, then the proof doesn't work as the Rank Nullity theorem is for finite dimensional vector spaces only . Thus, consider the first isomorphism theorem instead.

I had convinced my self that the first isomorphism theorem here would be sufficient by some quotient argument but I seem to have my self confused.

**Question:** Can someone thoroughly explain how one could use the first isomorphism theorem for the last part?

Comment: Would be better if you could lay out your first isomorphism theorem argument so that we could check if it is correct. Otherwise, the proof I know is the direct proof by constructing the isomorphism $x\mapsto (x-\alpha(x), \alpha(x))$.

Comment: Hi thanks for the argument. I thought that considering quotients should suffice but when I tried to lay it out as you mentioned I got stuck. I understand your argument. Do you see an obvious use of the first isomoprhism theorem instead?